# Chicago CTA pass on contactless bankcard or Apple Pay

Tags: tickets, public-transport, payment-cards, chicago

This question is about public transit in Chicago.  According to https://www.transitchicago.com/passes/, it is possible to load a CTA unlimited ride pass on a contactless bank card.  This seems like a good alternative to getting a Ventra card, but there isn't a lot of information as to how this actually works.

I am assuming that I can purchase a pass at a vending machine and choose an appropriate option to load it on a contactless card.  It would ask me to tap my bank card; and then I can tap my card at a turnstile to ride transit as long as the pass is valid.

- Is that how it works?
- Are there the right kind of vending machines at the Midway Airport L station?
- When I board transit, is there a way to check that it accepted my pass rather than charging a new fare to my card?
- Can this be used with Apple Pay instead of a physical contactless card?
- Is it necessary to have an online Ventra account for any of this to work?

Comment: A lot of your questions are answer here : https://www.ventrachicago.com/featured-questions/

Comment: @Max: I have read that page but I didn't see answers to any of these questions.  There is info about putting a pass on a Ventra card, and about paying with a contactless card on a pay-as-you-go basis, but nothing about a pass on a contactless card.  If I am missing something, can you please point it out?

Comment: Have you considered using the Ventra app w/ Apple Pay abilities? https://www.transitchicago.com/popular-ventra-transit-app-now-accepts-apple-pay/

Comment: @AussieJoe: Yes, that's a possibility.  But it would require creating an account, and the Ventra app on iPhone has really bad ratings, so I'm not entirely convinced that it would work reliably.

Comment: Actually that page says explicitly that you cannot put a pass on a contactless card.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: Where?  Are you looking at the question headed "Can I load regular fares/passes online or set up autoload to use Ventra with Apple Pay or Google Wallet?"  As far as I can tell, I think that's talking about whether you can put a pass on a Ventra card and *pay* for it with Apple Pay.  But it's quite unclear.

Comment: Aha, I see, the way they've worded it is a bit unclear. Nevertheless you can't load passes onto either contactless cards or * Pay apps (for now). It sounds like they might support this in the future, though.

Comment: Hmm. At this point I'd be more convinced if I could hear from someone that has actually tried it, since the page I linked (which is also official AFAIK) says very clearly that you can.

Comment: @NateEldredge ratings aside, it also states that the $5 account fee is refunded to you towards fare purchase. Might be your best bet, since the wording around contactless cards is unclear, as mentioned by MichaelHampton. Might be worth calling CTA to clarify. Just my two cents.

Comment: @AussieJoe: I'll be there in a couple days, so if I don't get an answer by then, I'll just try it myself and post my own answer.  I agree that getting a Ventra card would work okay, I was just wondering if I can avoid having another plastic card to throw away.  (And I think in order for the $5 rebate to be useful, I'd have to get the card, sit in the station registering it on my phone, and then add the pass to it after the credit posts.  Kind of a pain.)

Comment: @NateEldredge any chance of an answer?

Comment: @MarkMayo: Unfortunately I wasn't motivated enough to try it.  I just bought a pass on a disposable paper card which had no fee.  I did verify that Apple Pay works at the turnstile to pay per ride, however.